# Pandas dataframe timedelta column to format human readable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
data = df.groupby(['Jahr','Monat', 'Kunde'])['Dauer'].sum().reset_index(name='TD')
```

returns:

```
Jahr | Monat | Kunde | TD
2019 | 7     | C1    | 0 days 08:35:00
2019 | 8     | C1    | 10 days 04:05:00
2019 | 8     | C2    | 0 days 03:25:00
2019 | 9     | C1    | 10 days 09:15:00
2019 | 9     | C6    | 0 days 01:45:00
2019 | 9     | C3    | 0 days 02:30:00
2019 | 9     | C5    | 0 days 00:15:00
```

TD = timedelta

Instead of days I would like to receive the information in hours

I tried someting like that:
`data['TD'] / pd.Timedelta('1 hours')`

That will return for `10 days 04:05:00` `244.083333` (decimal hours) but I need `244.05` (hours and minutes)

I found several tips on how to convert it but is there nice way to get it all in `data = df.groupby(['Jahr','Monat', 'Kunde'])['Dauer'].sum().reset_index(name='TD')`

Edit 2019-10-07, 14:55:

```
Jahr | Monat | Kunde | TD
2019 | 7     | C1    | 0 days 08:35:00
2019 | 8     | C1    | 10 days 04:05:00
2019 | 8     | C2    | 0 days 03:25:00
2019 | 9     | C1    | 10 days 09:15:00
2019 | 9     | C6    | 0 days 01:45:00
2019 | 9     | C3    | 0 days 02:30:00
2019 | 9     | C5    | 0 days 00:15:00
```

should become

```
Jahr | Monat | Kunde | TD
2019 | 7     | C1    | 08:35:00
2019 | 8     | C1    | 244:05:00
2019 | 8     | C2    | 03:25:00
2019 | 9     | C1    | 249:15:00
2019 | 9     | C6    | 01:45:00
2019 | 9     | C3    | 02:30:00
2019 | 9     | C5    | 00:15:00
```

Comment: `That will return for 10 days 04:05:00 244.083333 but I need 244.05` - why `05` ?

Comment: That's a customer agreement i have no influence on.

Comment: hmmm, is is a bit weird, can you add expcted output from all data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove minutes and seconds by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), convert to strings and add zeros by [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) and then add minutes with slicinf timedeltas converted to strings:

```
floor_h = (data['TD'].dt.floor('H').div(pd.Timedelta('1 hours'))
                   .astype(int)
                   .astype(str)
                   .str.zfill(2))
data['TD'] = floor_h + ':' + data['TD'].astype(str).str[-15:-10]
print (data)
   Jahr  Monat Kunde         TD
0  2019      7    C1   08:35:00
1  2019      8    C1  244:05:00
2  2019      8    C2   03:25:00
3  2019      9    C1  249:15:00
4  2019      9    C6   01:45:00
5  2019      9    C3   02:30:00
6  2019      9    C5   00:15:00
```